# java.lang.AssertionError: on call of method in easy mock spring webflow junit

Tags: junit4, easymock, spring-webflow-2

I have tried to resume the flow with directly from particular state i.e `setCurrentState("initialFlowSetup")`. In which  the flow is transition to other state with the given eventid `error` but after certain transition there is one action involved **setErrorMessages.getErrorMessagesMap(flowRequestContext)" result="flowScope.errorMessageMap"** in state **set_error_in_scope** which is returning the Map.

When I call the method using EasyMock and set the expectation the return result as map in my test case  the return result is not taken by webflow. Below  is the error.

I am not able to understand the concept , when to set expectation and set the result to webflow so the return result will be identified by flow.

Error

```
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@7c974942 targetAction = [EvaluateAction@1eea9d2d expression = setErrorMessages.getErrorMessagesMap(flowRequestContext), resultExpression = flowScope.errorMessageMap], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'set_error_in_scope' of flow 'shclogin-flow' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState.doEnter(DecisionState.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.TransitionExecutingFlowExecutionExceptionHandler.handle(TransitionExecutingFlowExecutionExceptionHandler.java:111)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.FlowExecutionExceptionHandlerSet.handleException(FlowExecutionExceptionHandlerSet.java:109)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleException(Flow.java:600)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.tryFlowHandlers(FlowExecutionImpl.java:647)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleException(FlowExecutionImpl.java:603)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:263)
    at org.springframework.webflow.test.execution.AbstractFlowExecutionTests.resumeFlow(AbstractFlowExecutionTests.java:136)
    at com.shc.ecom.test.usr.TestloginlFlow.testAction(TestloginlFlow.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.ExpressionInvocationTargetException: A problem occurred when trying to execute method 'getErrorMessagesMap' on object of type [com.shc.ecom.sso.cas.web.flow.SetErrorMessages$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ae43a022]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.throwSimpleExceptionIfPossible(MethodReference.java:227)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:133)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:342)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call SetErrorMessages.getErrorMessagesMap([RequestControlContextImpl@48bfb884 externalContext = org.springframework.webflow.test.MockExternalContext@11653e3b, currentEvent = [null], requestScope = map[[empty]], attributes = map[[empty]], messageContext = [DefaultMessageContext@715fb77 sourceMessages = map[[null] -> list[[empty]]]], flowExecution = [FlowExecutionImpl@1b9c1b51 flow = 'shclogin-flow', flowSessions = list[[FlowSessionImpl@2e52fb3e flow = 'shclogin-flow', state = 'set_error_in_scope', scope = map['errorMessageMap' -> map['originalUrl' -> 123]]]]]]):
    SetErrorMessages.getErrorMessagesMap(requestContext): expected: 1, actual: 0
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:94)
    at com.shc.ecom.sso.cas.web.flow.SetErrorMessages$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ae43a022.getErrorMessagesMap(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129)
    ... 44 more
```

Xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.4.xsd" 
              start-state="initialFlowSetup" >


    <input name="loginId" value="requestScope.loginId" />
    <input name="logonPassword" value="requestScope.logonPassword" />
    <input name="sourceSiteId" value="requestScope.sourceSiteId" />
    <input name="fullpage" value="requestScope.fullpage" />
    <input name="partialuser" value="requestScope.partialuser" />
    <input name="sourceSiteId" value="flowScope.sourceSite" />
    <input name="service" value="requestScope.service" />
    <input name="redirectUrl" value="requestScope.redirectUrl" />
    <input name="sywLogin" value="requestScope.sywLogin" />
    <input name="tncmodal" value="requestScope.tncmodal" />
    <input name="modifyservice" value="requestScope.modifyservice" />
    <input name="reglogin" value="flowScope.reglogin" />
    <input name="enrollresponse" value="flowScope.enrollresponse" />
    <input name="shcCaptchaKey" value="requestScope.shcKey" />
    <input name="shcCaptchaResponse" value="requestScope.shcResponse" />
    <input name="sywmax" value="flowScope.sywmax" />
    <input name="auth" value="flowScope.auth" />
    <input name="maxactivationflow" value="flowScope.maxactivationflow" />


    <action-state id="initialFlowSetup">
        <evaluate expression="usrInitialFlowSetupAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="ticketGrantingTicketExistsCheck" />
        <transition on="error" to="pickup_error_redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <decision-state id="ticketGrantingTicketExistsCheck">
        <if test="flowScope.ticketGrantingTicketId != null" then="hasServiceCheck"
            else="gatewayRequestCheck" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="gatewayRequestCheck">
        <if
            test="externalContext.requestParameterMap['gateway'] != '' &amp;&amp; externalContext.requestParameterMap['gateway'] != null &amp;&amp; flowScope.service != null"
            then="redirect" else="submit" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="hasServiceCheck">
        <if test="flowScope.service != null" then="renewRequestCheck"
            else="viewGenericLoginSuccess" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="renewRequestCheck">
        <if
            test="externalContext.requestParameterMap['renew'] != '' &amp;&amp; externalContext.requestParameterMap['renew'] != null"
            then="submit" else="generateServiceTicket" />
    </decision-state>

    <!-- The "warn" action makes the determination of whether to redirect directly 
        to the requested service or display the "confirmation" page to go back to 
        the server. -->
    <decision-state id="warn">
        <if test="flowScope.warnCookieValue" then="showWarningView"
            else="redirect" />
    </decision-state>

    <!-- <action-state id="startAuthenticate"> <action bean="x509Check" /> <transition 
        on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" /> <transition on="error" to="viewLoginForm" 
        /> </action-state> -->
    <view-state id="viewLoginForm" view="casLoginView">
        <on-render>
            <evaluate expression="authenticationViaFormAction.setupForm()" />
            <evaluate expression="authenticationViaFormAction.referenceData()"/>
        </on-render>
        <transition on="submit" to="bindAndValidate" />
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="bindAndValidate">
        <evaluate expression="usrAuthenticationViaFormAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="submit" />
        <transition on="error" to="redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="submit">
        <evaluate expression = "usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.setCredentialsToFlowScope()" />
        <evaluate expression="usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.submit(flowRequestContext, flowScope.credentials, messageContext)" />
        <transition on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" />
        <transition on="authenticationFailure" to="pickup_error_redirect" />
        <transition on="error" to="pickup_error_redirect">
            <set name="errorCode" value="flowScope.errorCode" /> <!--  scope="conversation" />-->
        </transition>
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="sendTicketGrantingTicket">
        <evaluate expression="sendTicketGrantingTicketAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="serviceCheck" />
    </action-state>

    <decision-state id="serviceCheck">
        <if test="flowScope.service != null" then="checkEnrollResponse"
            else="viewGenericLoginSuccess" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="checkEnrollResponse">
        <if test="flowScope.enrollresponse != null" then="generateServiceTicket"
            else="checksywrrequired" />
    </decision-state>

    <!-- select the success modal based on the flow caller -->
    <decision-state id="checksywrrequired">
        <if test="requestScope.sywLogin == 'true'" then="sywrRequired"
            else="generateServiceTicket" />
    </decision-state>

    <action-state id="sywrRequired">
        <evaluate expression="usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="isAffinityCheckRequired" />
        <transition on="error" to="generateServiceTicketNoSywr" />
    </action-state>
    <decision-state id="isAffinityCheckRequired">
        <if test="requestScope.sourceSiteId==6" then="craftsmanAffinityCheck"
            else="generateServiceTicket" />
    </decision-state>
    <action-state id="craftsmanAffinityCheck">
    <evaluate expression="ssoGatewayService.searchUserByMemberNumberInTelluride(flowScope.sywrNumber,
                    requestParameters.sourceSiteId)" result="returnEmailResponse"/>
        <transition on="success" to="checkForCcAffinityModal" />
    </action-state>

    <!-- 
        <bean-action bean="ssoGatewayService" method="searchUserByMemberNumberInTelluride">
            <method-arguments>
                <argument expression="flowScope.sywrNumber" />
                <argument expression="${requestParameters.sourceSiteId}" />
            </method-arguments>
            <method-result name="returnEmailResponse" scope="flow" />
        </bean-action>
     -->

    <decision-state id="checkForCcAffinityModal">
        <if test="flowScope.returnEmailResponse.ccAffinity==true" then="generateServiceTicket"
            else="generateServiceTicketNoCcaffinity" />
    </decision-state>
    <action-state id="generateServiceTicketNoSywr">
        <evaluate expression="generateServiceTicketAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="sendtickettomodalforloginnosywr" />
        <transition on="error" to="setErrorCode" />
        <transition on="gateway" to="redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="generateServiceTicketNoCcaffinity">
        <evaluate expression="generateServiceTicketAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="sendtickettomodalforloginnoccaffinity" />
        <transition on="error" to="setErrorCode" />
        <transition on="gateway" to="redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="generateServiceTicket">
        <evaluate expression="generateServiceTicketAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="pickupticketmodal" />
        <transition on="error" to="setErrorCode" />
        <transition on="gateway" to="redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="setErrorCode">
        <evaluate expression="setErrorCodeBean.submit()" />
        <transition on="success" to="pickup_error_redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <!-- the "viewGenericLogin" is the end state for when a user attempts to 
        login without coming directly from a service. They have only initialized 
        their single-sign on session. -->
    <end-state id="viewGenericLoginSuccess" view="casLoginGenericSuccessView" />

    <!-- The "showWarningView" end state is the end state for when the user 
        has requested privacy settings (to be "warned") to be turned on. It delegates 
        to a view defines in default_views.properties that display the "Please click 
        here to go to the service." message. -->
    <end-state id="showWarningView" view="casLoginConfirmView" />

    <!-- The "redirect" end state allows CAS to properly end the workflow while 
        still redirecting the user back to the service required. -->
    <end-state id="redirect" view="externalRedirect:#{requestScope.response.url}" />

    <end-state id="viewServiceErrorView" view="viewServiceErrorView" />

    <end-state id="viewServiceSsoErrorView" view="viewServiceSsoErrorView" />


    <!-- select the success modal based on the flow caller -->
    <decision-state id="pickupticketmodal">
        <if test="flowScope.enrollresponse != null" then="sendtickettomodal_reg"
            else="sendTicket" />
    </decision-state>

    <!-- send the service ticket back to the modal, no view required in this 
        subflow -->
    <end-state id="sendtickettomodal_reg">
        <output name = "serviceTicketId" value = "requestScope.serviceTicketId"/>
    </end-state>

    <!-- <output-mapper>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.serviceTicketId}" target="serviceTicketId" />
        </output-mapper> -->

    <decision-state id="sendTicket">
        <if test="flowScope.auth != null &amp;&amp; flowScope.auth != ''"
            then="sendtickettomodalforloginnosywr" else="sendtickettomodalforlogin" />
    </decision-state>

    <end-state id="sendtickettomodalforlogin" view="/displayserviceticketandcookie">    
        <output name = "modifyservice" value = "requestScope.modifyservice"/>
        <output name = "sywmax" value = "requestScope.sywmax"/>
        <output name = "irp" value = "requestScope.irp"/>
        <output name = "auth" value = "requestScope.auth"/>
    </end-state>

    <!-- 
        <output-mapper>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.modifyservice}" target="modifyservice"/>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.sywmax}" target="sywmax"/>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.irp}" target="irp"/>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.auth}" target="auth"/>
        </output-mapper>
     -->

    <!-- for login, directly sending the st to the modal -->
    <end-state id="sendtickettomodalforloginnosywr" view="displayserviceticketandcookienosywr" >
        <output name = "modifyservice" value = "requestScope.modifyservice"/>
        <output name = "irp" value = "requestScope.irp"/>
    </end-state>
    <!-- 
        <output-mapper>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.modifyservice}" target="modifyservice" />
            <mapping source="${requestScope.irp}" target="irp" />
        </output-mapper>
     -->
    <end-state id="sendtickettomodalforloginnoccaffinity" view="displayserviceticketandcookienoccaffinity">
        <output name = "modifyservice" value = "requestScope.modifyservice"/>
        <output name = "irp" value = "requestScope.irp"/>
    </end-state>
    <!-- 
        <output-mapper>
            <mapping source="${requestScope.modifyservice}" target="modifyservice" />
            <mapping source="${requestScope.irp}" target="irp" />
        </output-mapper>
     -->

    <!-- for login, directly sending the st to the modal -->
    <end-state id="showTnCModal" view="/showTnCModalToUsers">

    </end-state>
    <!-- select the error redirect based on the flow caller -->
    <decision-state id="pickup_error_redirect">
        <if test="flowScope.enrollresponse != null" then="pickup_error_redirect_reg"
            else="set_error_in_scope" />
    </decision-state>

    <action-state id="set_error_in_scope">
        <evaluate expression="setErrorMessages.getErrorMessagesMap(flowRequestContext)" result="flowScope.errorMessageMap"
        result-type="java.util.HashMap"></evaluate>
        <transition on="success" to="pickup_error_redirect_login">  </transition>
    </action-state>

      <!-- redirect when error to create sso session, no view required in this subflow -->
    <end-state id="pickup_error_redirect_reg"  />


    <end-state id="pickup_error_redirect_login" view="/loginfailure" >
        <on-entry>
            <set name="flowScope.parameters" value="flowScope.errorMessageMap.parameters"></set>
        </on-entry>
    </end-state>


    <!-- current not properly defined the global error condition -->
    <global-transitions>
        <transition to="pickup_error_redirect"
            on-exception="org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.NoSuchFlowExecutionException" />
        <transition to="pickup_error_redirect"
            on-exception="org.jasig.cas.services.UnauthorizedSsoServiceException" />
        <transition to="pickup_error_redirect"
            on-exception="org.jasig.cas.services.UnauthorizedServiceException" />
        <transition to="pickup_error_redirect"
            on-exception="org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException" />
    </global-transitions>

</flow>
```

Test Case

```
 public class TestloginlFlow extends AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests {

    UsrInitialFlowSetupAction usrInitialFlowSetupAction;

    AuthenticationViaFormAction authenticationViaFormAction;

    UsrIsSYWRUserCheckAction usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction;

    SSOGatewayService ssoGatewayService;

    CustomGenerateServiceTicketAction generateServiceTicketAction;

    CentralAuthenticationService centralAuthenticateService;

    CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator warnCookieGenerator;

    USRAuthenticationViaFormAction usrAuthenticationViaFormAction;

    List<ArgumentExtractor> argumentExtractor;

    SetErrorMessages setErrorMessages;
    RequestControlContext requestContext;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        usrInitialFlowSetupAction = EasyMock.createMock("usrInitialFlowSetupAction", UsrInitialFlowSetupAction.class); // usrAuthenticationViaFormAction
        setErrorMessages = EasyMock.createMock("SetErrorMessages", SetErrorMessages.class);
        usrAuthenticationViaFormAction = EasyMock.createMock("usrAuthenticationViaFormAction",
                USRAuthenticationViaFormAction.class);
        usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction = EasyMock.createMock("usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction", UsrIsSYWRUserCheckAction.class); // ssoGatewayService

        ssoGatewayService = EasyMock.createMock("ssoGatewayService", SSOGatewayService.class);
        generateServiceTicketAction = EasyMock.createMock("generateServiceTicketAction",
                CustomGenerateServiceTicketAction.class);
        centralAuthenticateService = EasyMock.createMock("centralAuthenticateService",
                CentralAuthenticationService.class);
        warnCookieGenerator = EasyMock.createMock("centralAuthenticateService", CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator.class);
        argumentExtractor = EasyMock.createMock("argumentExtractors", List.class);
        generateServiceTicketAction = EasyMock.createMock("generateServiceTicketAction",
                CustomGenerateServiceTicketAction.class);
        requestContext=EasyMock.createMock("requestContext",RequestControlContext.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected FlowDefinitionResource getResource(FlowDefinitionResourceFactory resourceFactory) {
        return resourceFactory.createFileResource("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/usr/flows/shclogin-flow.xml");
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerMockFlowBeans(ConfigurableBeanFactory builderContext) {

        builderContext.registerSingleton("argumentExtractors", argumentExtractor);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("warnCookieGenerator", warnCookieGenerator);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("centralAuthenticateService", centralAuthenticateService);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("usrAuthenticationViaFormAction", usrAuthenticationViaFormAction);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction", usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("ssoGatewayService", ssoGatewayService);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("generateServiceTicketAction", generateServiceTicketAction);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator", warnCookieGenerator);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("setErrorMessages", setErrorMessages);
        builderContext.registerSingleton("request", requestContext);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configureFlowBuilderContext(MockFlowBuilderContext builderContext) {

        usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.setCentralAuthenticationService(centralAuthenticateService);
        usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.setWarnCookieGenerator(warnCookieGenerator);
        builderContext.registerBean("warnCookieGenerator", warnCookieGenerator);
        builderContext.registerBean("centralAuthenticateService", centralAuthenticateService);
        builderContext.registerBean("usrAuthenticationViaFormAction", usrAuthenticationViaFormAction);
        builderContext.registerBean("usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction", usrIsSYWRUserCheckAction);
        builderContext.registerBean("ssoGatewayService", ssoGatewayService);
        builderContext.registerBean("generateServiceTicketAction", generateServiceTicketAction);
        builderContext.registerBean("setErrorMessages", setErrorMessages);
        builderContext.registerBean("request", requestContext);

    }

    public void testAction() throws Exception {
        setCurrentState("initialFlowSetup");
        MockExternalContext ctx = new MockExternalContext();
        MutableAttributeMap input = new LocalAttributeMap();
        MockRequestControlContext context = new MockRequestControlContext();

        FlowExecution flowExecution = getFlowExecution();
        FlowSession session = flowExecution.getActiveSession();
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("originalUrl", 123);
        session.getScope().put("errorMessageMap", model);

        updateFlowExecution(flowExecution);
        ctx.setEventId("error");
        EasyMock.expect(setErrorMessages.getErrorMessagesMap(requestContext)).andReturn(model);
        EasyMock.replay(setErrorMessages);

        resumeFlow(ctx);
        assertResponseWrittenEquals("/loginfailure", ctx);
        assertFlowExecutionEnded();

    }

    public void testAction1() throws Exception {
    // setCurrentState("initialFlowSetup");
    MockExternalContext ctx = new MockExternalContext();
    MutableAttributeMap input = new LocalAttributeMap();

    input.put("loginId", "12");
    input.put("logonPassword", "ankur");
    input.put("sourceSiteId", "3");
    input.put("fullpage", "");
    input.put("partialuser", "true");
    input.put("service", "");
    input.put("redirectUrl", "");
    input.put("sywLogin", "er4fju");
    input.put("tncmodal", null);
    input.put("modifyservice", "no");
    // input.put("reglogin", false);
    // input.put("enrollresponse", 200);
    input.put("shcCaptchaKey", null);
    input.put("ticketGrantingTicketId", "1234");
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("renew", "yes");
    ParameterMap requestParameterMap = new LocalParameterMap(parameters);
    ctx.setRequestParameterMap(requestParameterMap);
    MockRequestContext context = new MockRequestContext();
    Event event = new Event(this, "success");
    EasyMock.expect(usrInitialFlowSetupAction.doExecute(flowRequestContext)).andReturn(event);
    EasyMock.replay(usrInitialFlowSetupAction);

    //Mockito.mock(usrInitialFlowSetupAction.doExecute(flowRequestContext), event)
    /*
     * FlowExecution flowExecution = getFlowExecution(); FlowSession session
     * = flowExecution.getActiveSession();
     * session.getScope().put("ticketGrantingTicketId", "ee");
     */
    // updateFlowExecution(flowExecution);

    startFlow(input, ctx);

}

}
```

Comment: @rptmat57 Hi I have started writing junit for new flow in which java.lang.assertion error is coming because of easy mock  can you please let me know the concept why the return result is not being identified by webflow even though I am returning the expected result for method call

Comment: @rptmat57 did you get any chance to look into this issue I have tried but not getting the concept why this is failing

Comment: @rptmat57 Hi I have added one more test cases with this new flow but getting same assertion error where I need to pass spring webflow RequestContext in method I Tried to pass MockRequestContext but not getting any help. I am not sure what are the parameter we need to set in MockRequestContext